# SWIFT: parse.com chek push notification before showing

Tags: swift, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

How to check push notification before showing in swift?

I want check data and if incorrect data I don't want show notification

**UPDATE CODE**

my code:

I just use simple Parse.com example. This is my AppDelegate class

```
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var singInCallback: (()->())?

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        Parse.setApplicationId("//",
            clientKey: "//")

        // Register for Push Notitications
        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.


            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")

            var pushPayload = false

            if let options = launchOptions {
                pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {


                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }

        var notificationActionAccept :UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        notificationActionAccept.identifier = "FIRST_ACTION"
        notificationActionAccept.title = "Įvertinti"

        var notificationCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        notificationCategory.identifier = "CallNotificationCategory"
        notificationCategory .setActions([notificationActionAccept], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: NSSet(array:[notificationCategory]) as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // check if app opened because user tapped on notification
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let notificationDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
                self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notificationDictionary)
            }
        }

        return 
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
    {
            return 
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        print(userInfo)

        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just proof your data.... if it's correct -> show notification, if not -> perform nothing in else....: Please post your current code.

Comment: I add my AppDelegate class